# How to get sum and count based on month interval in R

Tags: mysql

I have following table in MySQL (Version - 5.7.18-log).

```
ID      Old_Date       Curr_Date             Status       Price       items
ID-1    2021-07-14     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Done         1500        3
ID-1    2021-06-26     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Hold         3500        6
ID-1    2021-03-04     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Done         5000        3
ID-1    2021-01-11     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Done         2800        2
```

From above table, I need to fetch the count of `ID`s where status is `Done` in last 1, 6  and 9 month interval. Also need to fetch highest `Price` in last 12 month.

The interval needs to be calculated between `Old_Date` and `Curr_Date`.

Required Output-

```
ID     1_Month_Done   6_Month_Done    9_Month_Done   Highest_Price
ID-1   0              2               3              5000
```

Comment: There appear to be 2, not 1, records occurring within the last 6 months.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen- Yes, My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, Old_Date, Curr_Date) <= 1) AS 1_Month_Done,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, Old_Date, Curr_Date) <= 6) AS 6_Month_Done,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, Old_Date, Curr_Date) <= 9) AS 9_Month_Done,
    MAX(Price) AS Highest_Price
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I put condition to fetch only those highest price where Status = Done.

Comment: Use: `MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Done' THEN Price END)`

Comment: Biegelesien - Apologies, but how can I get sum of `Items` as well for the same interval.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're asking for now.

Comment: Biegelesien - I'm trying to retrieve sum of `Items` value in for 1, 6 and 9 month interval.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, Old_Date, Curr_Date) <= 1 THEN items ELSE 0 END) AS 1_M_Items` ... and so on